# MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy() not working on Google AI-Platform (CMLE)

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-estimator, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm getting the following error while using **MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()** for training Custom Estimator on Google AI-Platform (CMLE).

```
ValueError: Unrecognized task_type: 'master', valid task types are: "chief", "worker", "evaluator" and "ps".
```

Both **MirroredStrategy()** and **PamameterServerStrategy()** are working fine on AI-Platform with their respective `config.yaml` files. I'm currently ***not*** providing device scopes for any operations. ***Neither*** I'm providing any device filter in session config, `tf.ConfigProto(device_filters=device_filters)`.

The `config.yaml` file which I'm using for training with **MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()** is:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_gpu
  workerType: standard_gpu
  workerCount: 4
```

The `masterType` input is mandatory for submitting the training job on AI-Platform.

Note: It's showing 'chief' as a valid task type and 'master' as invalid. I'm providing tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0 in setup.py for trainer package.

Comment: Chief, etc. refer to tensorflow 2.0.  ai platform may be running 1.x runtime

Comment: Hi @Lak. I didn't get the error, its showing 'chief' as a **valid** task type and 'master' as **invalid**.  I'm providing `tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0` in `setup.py` for trainer package.

Comment: I' ve updated the question with your comment above (that you are using tensorflow-gpu) and answered below

Comment: @SWAPNILMASUREKAR could you try again on AI Platform Training?  This might have been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) This appears to be a bug then with MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy. Please file a bug in TensorFlow. In TensorFlow 1.x, it should be using master and in TensorFlow 2.x, it should be using chief. The code is (wrongly) asking for chief, and AI Platform (because you are using 1.14) is providing only master. Incidentally: master = chief + evaluator.

(2) Do not have add tensorflow to your setup.py.  Provide the tensorflow framework you want AI Platform to use using the `--runtime-version` (See https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/runtime-version-list) flag to gcloud.

Answer (score 2):

I got into same issue. As far I understand MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy config values are different from other strategies and from what CMLE provides by default: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_keras#multi-worker_configuration

It doesn't support 'master' node, it calls it 'chief' instead.
If you are running your jobs in container, you can try using 'useChiefInTfConfig' flag, see documentation here: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/ml/v1/python/latest/ml_v1.projects.jobs.html

Otherwise you might try hacking your TF_CONFIG manually:

```
  TF_CONFIG = os.environ.get('TF_CONFIG')
  if TF_CONFIG and '"master"' in TF_CONFIG:
    os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = TF_CONFIG.replace('"master"', '"chief"')
```